# how to replace single quotes to doubles in vs code using the search(Ctrl + Shift + F) button?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

i have a Nodejs project that uses single quotes and double quotes but now I want to follow same  standard(use double quotes in entire of the project). so how to replace all the single quotes to double quotes?
i search them like this
`'(.+?)'`
but how to replace them?

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+H is the command you need.

Comment: Your regular expression doesn't really honour the syntax of JavaScript.  In particular, it's possible to escape quotes within strings.  e.g.:  `'it\'s "hot" isn\'t it'`  Would not only break after replacing single quotes with double quotes, it would also alter literal characters of the body of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the icon on the left of the search that looks like `>`, then you can put in your replacement string.

As a side note, you can also simply search for `'` and replace with `"`. Be careful when doing this - review the instances of `'` first, or replace one by one.

Comment: Please upvote and accept answers that answer your question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The open and close quotes are the same, just search `'` and replace with `"` .

Comment: You probably meant `"` instead of `”`.

Comment: I’m typing with phone keyboard and don’t have all symbols on my iphone keyboard.